# Why is there no color in my lava material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I followed a tutorial and it looked great there but mine has no color and also has no displacement either. tutorial i followed here: https://youtu.be/B4XDBG4m3d0
[image]

Comment: Hello, make sure to connect the output of the Mix Shader to the Surface input of the Material Output. Also, if you want true displacement, enable Displacement in the material properties instead of Bump

Comment: thank you very much, I can't believe i missed that.

Comment: I do have one more question, see the edit i made to the original question

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing an unrelated existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable *Displacement Only* or *Displacement and Bump* in the settings for this material.

[image: desc]

Also your AO node is currently connected to the *Material Output*.

[image]